# What's the word for someone who can look good in different styles / looks

Tags: single-word-requests

What's the word for someone who can look good in different styles / looks, suddenly can't remember the word

Comment: ...a good-looker"?

Comment: Fashionably versatile?

Comment: Maybe just *stylish.*

Answer (score 2):

"**Clothes-horse**" has been suggested to me:

OED:

> **b. figurative. A person whose main function is or appears to be to wear or show off clothes.**
>
> 1948   Richmond (Va.) Times-Dispatch 22 July 18/2 (headline)    *Janis Paige, Best Clothes-horse, Looks Good Here, Too.*
>
> 1962   J. Ludwig in R. Weaver Canad. Short Stories (1968) 2nd Ser. 249   *She ordered her chauffeur to drive her to Fifi's, Shmifi's—a fancy French place for clothes horses.*

Although it does not say so, I assume that the meaning is also "fashion model" who, as an attribute, have to look good in all styles.

Comment: Actually the definition doesn’t imply that the “clothes-horse” looks good in different style clothes.

Comment: @user66974 If their *main function is or appears to be to wear or show off clothes,*" are they going to keep their job/reputation and/or succeed if they look awful in 50% of styles?

Comment: I would probably just say that he/she looks good in anything.